# npm postinstall script with published package

Tags: node.js, npm, package, artifact, post-install

I just created my package and published it to artifact registry.
This package has `postinstall` script that works if I do `npm i` inside package directory, even if there is no `node_modules` directory.

Inside `postinstall` script I use `patch-package` from npm to overwrite few dependencies.

The problem is when I install this package in other project with `npm i -s @my/package`.
When `postinstall` script is executing it doesn`t find those packages and throw errors.

I tried to execute `patch-package` in parent directory but it does not find those packages anyway.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I just found out that if i run `npm i -s @my/package --dry-run` it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

To fix problem I added in `postinstall` script installation script for those packages `npm i dep1@0.0.0 dep2@0.0.0 dep3@0.0.0 && rest...`.