# npm 8.19 (node 18) not running prepare or postinstall scripts from packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, post-install

I have a custom package with a `postinstall` script, this script used to be run automatically when using `npm install` in the applications that required the package. We recently updated this package from using Angular 7 to Angular 15. In doing this we update our system from requiring Node 10 to Node 18, 18.12.1 with npm 8.19 to be precise.

When using npm 8.19 now the script doesn't run anymore when the package is installed and I have no idea why (I've tried checking with `--foreground-scripts` but no extra output was given), I even tried changing from `postinstall` to `prepare` but it didn't help

I have already tried what suggested here:

[npm postinstall script with published package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274402/npm-postinstall-script-with-published-package)

[NPM not running postinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73155672/npm-not-running-postinstall)

But it didn't help either